# request.session variables are disappearing on their own

Tags: python, django, session-variables

I am setting a session variables everytime I logged in.
The thing is, if I use the local ip '127.0.0.1:8000' to run my python-django web, the session variables is working properly. But if I use my original IP '192.168.2*.***' after I set the value of every session variables, after seconds the variables itself cannot be called, I mean I got an error the session variables isn't declared 'KeyError: username'

This is my codes in logging in, I use ajax and replace the document.location.href to Home url if the ajax data returns 'valid'

```
   @csrf_exempt
    def CheckLogin(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            id = request.POST['id']
            query = query_api(
                "SELECT * FROM user_tbl WHERE employee_id='" + id + "';")
            if len(query) == 0:
                return JsonResponse({"data": "Invalid username"}, safe=False)
    
            request.session['test'] = "asdjkahsdkjhk"
            request.session['logged_in'] = True
            request.session['username'] = id
            request.session['password'] = "1234"
            request.session['role'] = query[0]["role"]
            
            test = json.dumps(query, indent=4, cls=DateTimeEncoder)
            return JsonResponse({"data": "valid", "password": test, "role": query[0]["role"]}, safe=False)
    
        return JsonResponse({"data": "invalid ajax"}, safe=False)
```

While these are my codes in checking whether it is for log in or already logged-in.

```
@csrf_exempt
def CheckifLoggedin(request):
    if 'logged_in' in request.session:
        return JsonResponse({"data": "logged_in"}, safe=False)

    return JsonResponse({"data": "for log-in"}, safe=False)
```

If I try to get the username using this code:

username = request.session['username']

it just return this error: KeyError: username

and yeah, If I use 127.0.0.1:8000 as the default url server, it works well but If I use my IP it doesn't.

These are the codes in my settings.py

```
DEBUG = True

CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['http://192.168.2*.***:8000', '192.168.2*.***:8000']

SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS = '3600'
SECURE_HSTS_INCLUDE_SUBDOMAINS = True
SECURE_HSTS_PRELOAD = True
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['192.168.2*.***', '127.0.0.1', 'localhost']

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # 'corsheaders',#ADDED DJANGO APPS
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    #MY APPS
    'dashboard',

    #ADDED DJANGO APPS
    'rest_framework',
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.DjangoModelPermissions',
    )
}

MIDDLEWARE = [
    # 'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

# CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
# CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True

ROOT_URLCONF = 'nfpo.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'nfpo.wsgi.application'
```

Session variables are disappearing after 1 request.
Also, I found out that using my IP to run the server doesn't save session in the database. What do I do?

Comment: Each host like localhost or 127.0.0.1 are treated differently by Django. Might be a change in your IP address. Or the might be the server restart.

Comment: I'm stuck on it 8 hrs already. hays I'll try restarting my pc. i'll be back

Comment: @SivaSankar I found out that if I use my IP to run the app, it don't save the session in the database. what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution, I created a temporary app that creates session data that works perfectly and copied its' settings to my main app.